# Unable to set up basic authentication with Spring Boot REST API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to set up a RESTful API with Spring Boot and I'm trying to enable basic authentication. How come I keep hitting a 403 Access Denied error? I'm sending my credentials as a header in Postman (see image attached). If I remove `.anyRequest.authenticated()`, it works fine. I don't want to remove that though because I would like basic authentication for every endpoint. What am I doing wrong?

## `Application.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

## `SecurityConfiguration.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

## `Controller.java`

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After digging around in the Spring docs, it seems I understand what each of the chained method calls are for.

Anyway, the simple answer is that I needed `.and().httpBasic()` to enable Basic HTTP Authentication over my REST API.

`.anyRequest().authenticated()` simply mandates that every request is authenticated, but did not specify what method. Adding basic authentication means we can use basic auth to authenticate a user.

[See more.](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/html/jc.html)